# Npm Errors after installations

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

So I have been trying to reinstall my node-modules and for some reason I am encountering this error I have tried many things like `npm i -g windows-build-tools` and it did not work.

````
npm ERR! path C:\Quentin\Discordbot\node_modules\@discordjs\opus
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Quentin\Discordbot\node_modules\@discordjs\opus\prebuild\node-v88-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown\opus.node --module_name=opus --module_path=C:\Quentin\Discordbot\node_modules\@discordjs\opus\prebuild\node-v88-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.1.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@15.13.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "C:\Quentin\Discordbot\node_modules\@discordjs\opus\prebuild\node-v88-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown\opus.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/discordjs/opus/releases/download/v0.3.3/opus-v0.3.3-node-v88-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 404 https://github.com/discordjs/opus/releases/download/v0.3.3/opus-v0.3.3-node-v88-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://github.com/discordjs/opus/releases/download/v0.3.3/opus-v0.3.3-node-v88-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for @discordjs/opus@0.3.3 and node@15.13.0 (node-v88 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 404 status code downloading tarball https://github.com/discordjs/opus/releases/download/v0.3.3/opus-v0.3.3-node-v88-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown.tar.gz```
````

Comment: you deleted the package-lock file before you do npm install ?

Comment: Sir you have helped me a lot i did not know what to do thanku

Comment: you are welcome